# Play local mp3 music if online radio stream stops playing on VLC

Tags: vlc

I am in the middle of Raspberry pi project using VLC, where I want to play online radio all the time through the Raspberry 24/7. But if there is an network drop/disconnection, VLC should automatically drop the radio stream and start playing locally stored mp3. How can I do this using VLC?

I tried to create a playlist and added the streaming link and the mp3 files, but the stream did not stop or stop and skip to next mp3 file.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible without code.. nor is SO the correct place for this question, I guess

Answer (score 0):

Well VLC seems to be a broken when it comes to stopping streams after a designated time. there is an argument --stop-time or --run-time but its broken and does not work as per the documentation.

The issue is that you have a make a dirty solution where you will have to check through other means (i-e programming) that the conditions to play stored mp3 are met then you kill running VLC and start another instance with the stored music playlist.

Its a dirty solution and I would never opt for such a thing. If you are aware of ffmpeg then try it.